# Como alterar a cor e fundo de texto selecionado com o mouse?

Tags: css

Quando selecionamos um texto com o mouse em um website o texto fica com uma cor branca e com um fundo azul (acho que pode variar de navegador para navegador). Porém eu gostaria de saber se é possível trocar a cor e o fundo desse texto somente com CSS, e se tem uma solução que dê suporte aos diversos navegadores.

Veja um exemplo da alteração que eu gostaria de fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apenas isto `::selection`

Comment: Mas só com esse pseudo-elemento os efeitos vão ser aplicados em todos os navegadores?

Comment: A partir de: **Chrome 4.0**, **IE 9.0**, **Firefox 2.0**, **Safari 3.1**, **Opera 10.1**. Sendo que para o Firefox é necessário utilizar o prefixo **-moz-**

Comment: Talvez este link possa te ajudar: https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Comment: @LeAndrade Show mano! Obrigado pelo aviso, é de grande ajuda!

Comment: @MikeOtharan muito bom o conteúdo do link! Obrigado por compartilhar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você consegue esse efeito usando o pseudo-elemento `::selection`.

O `pseudo-element` tem suporte para a maioria dos navegadores inclusive `IE-9`, mas na data de hoje `24/10/18` não há suporte para o `IOS Safari` e nem para o `Opera Mini` como pode ser visto no site [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection).

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```css
::selection {
    background-color: red;
    color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae porta purus, in tincidunt dui. Ut ut neque neque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut porttitor convallis purus sed porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac velit turpis. Integer sed dui quam. Suspendisse laoreet aliquam velit, sed interdum sapien. Donec id nisl non libero vehicula malesuada rutrum auctor ex. </p>
```

**Obs:** Para versões <=61 do firefox, é necessário utilizar a seguinte sintaxe:

`::-moz-selection`

**Referência:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo e pelas dicas em relação aos navegadores Jorge!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade *css* `::selection`, fiz um breve exemplo para facilitar no aprendizado.

```css
.exemplo-background::selection {
  background: #e74c3c;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.45;
  background: #E0DCCC;
  color: #333;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<p class='exemplo-background'>Você pode alterar a cor de fundo ao selecionar esse texto.</p>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzQLyO

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo André! Muito bom!

Comment: Valeu @JoãoPedroSchmitz, abraços!